# how to solve kotlin coroutine annotation warning

Tags: kotlin, annotations, build.gradle, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

let me ask

I use kotlin coroutine

```
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
GlobalScope.launch {
    displaySura()
}
```

and in the build tab showing warning:

```
This annotation should be used with the compiler argument '-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
```

how to solve this warning?
thanks in advance

Comment: Aside from the question itself (which has been answered), it must be noted that this situation doesn't seem like a valid use case for the use of `GlobalScope`. If you launch a coroutine to display something, it's likely it should be cancelled when leaving this screen. Take a look at `lifecycleScope` and `viewModelScope` if you're on Android, they should be better suited than `GlobalScope`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add `-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn` compiler argument in the build file:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i use this in app/build.gradle
`tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ["-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"]
}`

Comment: where to put your code here?

Comment: in the build file. Do you have some build file for your project? For example for android it's `build.gradle`

Comment: Can also be put inside android block in gradle. 

Example - android { kotlinOptions { } }

Comment: Can someone please explain why it's even necessary?

Answer (score 7):

To clarify to @Sergio's answer, you can add the block here in your app's build.gradle file

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
        ]
    }
```